# Company public IP is being blocked by Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a VM hosted on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) providing a web service, which is accessible from everywhere except my company IP.

I trace-routed the connection from office to the GCP VM and it breaks at an IP `72.14.218.142`. And it seems like it is a IP block service after I did a `whois` on it.

Does anyone has suggestions?

**Updated host settings here:**
GCP server IP: 34.85.91.xxx 
Company Public IP: 60.250.XX.XX and 210.64.YY.YY

60.250.XX.XX is unable to reach out to the GCP server while 210.64.YY.YY can ping it.

Comment: Do you have a site to site vpn tunnel to your cloud instance?

Comment: Hi @Citizen,
I dont, just all traffic goes thru internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`72.14.218.142` is advertised by Google, which by itself does not answer anything. Whether your IPAM or GCP knows anything about it in logs or documentation would be interesting.

Test the reachability of that web service through as many paths as possible. All your organization's ISPs, monitoring services you use, multiple cloud providers, residential commodity broadband. Basic tests: HTTP, ICMP echo, traceroute.

Provide that test data to anyone responsible for the networks where it fails. Your network and security staff, architects who designed this cloud infrastructure, ISPs. Find the fault. Check for functional paths, firewall access lists.

Edit: Server Fault is limited in how we can help you with GCP tech support, we are a volunteer community. Enable a [GCP support plan](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/options) and open a case. Same thing for ISPs and vendors, you should have a support agreement such that you can have them take a look.

This is mostly an exercise in cross-domain cooperation. Lean on the business importance of this thing to get everyone to help you.

Comment: Hi @John Mahowald,
Thanks for the reply. I did have done the basic test mentioned above. and found a previous discussion may be relevant to what I am encountering <br>
https://serverfault.com/a/800951/553826 <br>
According to this thread suggestion, I have to reach out to GPC to unblock my IP.
But there is no email notice has been sent to me and the only clue is that GCP support document suggests to post an issue here in serverfault...
Do you happen to know the GCP contact info?

Comment: What ISPs are in the failing path, at what routers from traceroute output (add traceroute to your question)?

Comment: Re: support, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

There might be the case where your company IP "60.250.XX.XX" is on a embargoed country as per the following [link](https://support.google.com/ethics/answer/6290111).

As a side note, I realize that GCP is not mentioned there but that still applies to GCP resources.